# Lines between all possible points in a plane

Tags: matlab, matrix, lines

I'm trying to draw lines between every point in a plane given the x,y coordinates in an nx2 matrix. So if I have 4 points in the array (named 'A'), there should be 6 connections total. The current code will only give me one line connecting to the next point.

```
line(A(:,1),A(:,2))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
clear all;
A =[0,0; 0,1 ;1,0 ;1,1]; 
N = max(size(A));
for k = 1:N
 for l = k:N
     line(A(k,:),A(l,:))
 end
end
```

Comment: great solution, but i feel like there is a little typo and it should be 
`line(A(k,:),A(l,:))`

Comment: @Finn Thank you, fixed it.